# Comma separated values in a string to function arguments

Tags: php

```
function foobar($arg1 , $arg2) { 

    echo $arg1.arg2;

};
```

is there any way to call it like this:

```
$args =  'foo, bar';
foobar($args);
```

I know I can do this with a array, but my foobar() already have a lot of code calling it with 2 arguments.

Thank you,

mjs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) for this. Like so:

```
call_user_func_array('foobar', explode(',', $args));
```

This would be the same as doing:

```
foobar('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: Thanks alexn, I've marked @mfonda answer correct just because he was the first, although your answer is more complete, have an upvote instead.

Comment: No problems, but for the record, i was 27 seconds faster :)

Comment: Ok, here you go, now I feel bad for mfonda :(

Answer (score 1):

`call_user_func_array('foobar', explode(', ', 'foo, bar'));` should do the trick.